# xcodebuild not building library for simulator

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk, ios-simulator

I'm running a script to build a static library for the device and the simulator to later be merged using lipo.

To build both versions I'm using the following commands:

```
xcodebuild -target ${L_NAME} -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphonesimulator -arch i386 BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}"

xcodebuild -target ${L_NAME} ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphoneos  BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}"
```

The problem is that no iphonesimulator version is created. Inside the Products folder only a Debug-iphoneos version exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found out the problem, I didn't have i386 as a valid architecture